# Creationg trigger to restrict NULL value for new address record

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

I have tried to create trigger, which remind users to avoid null value in address1 if role is Company.
This is where I ended up:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "SCHEMA"."ADDRESS_VALUE"                          
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON "SCHEMA"."TABLE1"
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  ADDRESS TABLE1.ADDRESS1%TYPE;   
  V_CNT NUMBER; 
BEGIN
  ADDRESS := :NEW.ADDRESS1;
  IF :OLD.ADDRESS1 = ADDRESS THEN
    RETURN;
  END IF;

  SELECT COUNT(1)
    INTO V_CNT    
    FROM SCHEMA.TABLE2 
   WHERE ROLE = 'COMPANY';

  IF V_CNT > 0 THEN 
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20101,' ADDRESS IS MANDATORY');              
  END IF;
END;
```

This seems to work properly and gives a message, "address is mandatory" if users tries to leave it as null but message still keep up coming even if they try to add something in address1. It kind a stuck there and will not allow continue even mandatory field is <> null. Whats wrong?

Can you please help me with this annoying issue. Thanks.

Oracle 11g in use.

Regards,
Almost first ever trigger

Comment: What is the output of `SELECT COUNT(1)
INTO V_CNT    
FROM SCHEMA.TABLE2 
WHERE ROLE = 'COMPANY';` it must be greater than 0. and you have not used any reference of what values are inserted or updated in this query.

Comment: Also, Inserts do not have `:OLD` values. Hence, while `INSERTING` your first `IF` condition will fail all the time

Comment: `TABLE1` and `TABLE2` definitions would greatly help.

Comment: In address1 field should be add street-addrss (in TABLE1). It cannot be [null] in case if role = COMPANY (role taken from TABLE2). If using :NEW, does it mean inserting will work? What about update?

Comment: I'm not sure what `:OLD` is needed for. You are checking what the value will be, so no need to see what it was. Also, the comparison `:OLD.ADDRESS1 = ADDRESS` is odd. Try this: `IF :NEW.ADDRESS1 IS NULL THEN` and do your role check after that. Keep in mind that equality comparisons don't work for `NULL`.

Comment: Hi Ted, That :OLD was meant to handled existing address1 record if it tried to update as null. And with existing Records this trigger works but not for new ones. I did that what you mentioned (and did it already earlier) "IF :NEW.ADDRESS1..." but it didnt work. Didn´t raise exception.

Answer (score 0):

Your trigger has several issues. It seems you have a conditional not null column, a poor design at best. The assistance of the "COMPANY" role dictates whether address1 is allowed to be null. If the role it exists at all, it does not have to be related to the row being processed, then Address1 cannot be null for any row. So what will you do with existing null address1 rows when the role is initially added.  
 
There's the issue of the non existing old record for inserts. You test to see if address1 has changed; I guess you can claim that going form not existing to existing technically qualifies as changed. It'll work, but is deferentially not the recommended approach. TO correct we'll get rid of it entirely. 
Finally, your main complaint that the exception is thrown even when address1 is known to be not null. This is due to the fact that you didn't even test it's content for null.You threw the exception if "COMPANY" role exists. Essentially, you trigger says "if the role "COMPANY" exists in table2 do not permit inserts on table1 nor updates to existing address1 values in table1".  
Try the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "SCHEMA"."ADDRESS_VALUE"                          
BEFORE INSERT 
    OR UPDATE of address1 
    ON "SCHEMA"."TABLE1"
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE 
  V_CNT NUMBER; 
BEGIN
  if :new.address1 is null
  then 
      SELECT COUNT(1)
        INTO V_CNT    
        FROM SCHEMA.TABLE2 
       WHERE ROLE = 'COMPANY';

      IF V_CNT > 0 THEN 
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20101,' ADDRESS IS MANDATORY');              
      END IF;
  end if;
END;
```

What's changed? Well first notice the change in the trigger header, specifically the UPDATE specification. The revision eliminates your need it check if it's changed on the update. If it did not change the trigger does not fire. Secondly, the existence of the role is checked only if the new address1 is null, if its not null the role existing or not does not matter.  
Finally, there's the potential issue of the row not being related to the an "COMPANY" role but failing allowed null-ability because it exists. We need definition of the relationship between the tables and the DDL for both of them to comment on that.